# Series with factorial.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Evaluate $$\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{3}{4!}+...+\frac{99}{100!}$$

My attempt,

I changed it into $$\sum_{n=1}^{99} \frac{n}{(n+1)!}$$

I really don't know how to attempt for it as it consists of factorial. Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: @labbhattacharjee It helps a lot!

Comment: Hint: $n=(n+1)-1$.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Hint** $$\frac{n}{(n+1)!}= \frac{n+1 -1}{(n+1)!} =\frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$$

Answer (score 8):

This is a classic example of a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)! It'd first be nice to shift the limits of summation to get the factorial of a more comfortable function, and then we can split up the fraction to show how it telescopes:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{99} \frac{n}{(n+1)!} &= \sum_{n=2}^{100} \frac{n-1}{n!} \\
&= \sum_{n=2}^{100} \frac{1}{(n-1)!} - \frac{1}{n!} \\
&= \frac{1}{(2-1)!} - \frac{1}{100!} \\
&= 1- \frac{1}{100!}
\end{align}$$

As an aside, note that the result of this series converges towards $1$ as $n$ approaches infinity.